# setting up friendly urls using urlrewriter.net shows actual url

Tags: c#, .net

Im playing around with urlrewriter.net and setting up some friendly urls.  Ive set up a mapping but ive noticed that the url in the address bar changes from the friendly address to the actual address.  I was under the impression that this would be masked from the user.  Am i missing something here.

```
<redirect url="~/products/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Default.aspx?category=$1&amp;type=$2" />
```

Friendly url

```
http://localhost:58358/products/dvds/metal
```

Actual url

```
http://localhost:58358/Default.aspx?category=dvds&type=metal
```

Comment: It makes sense, as you are using a `redirect` rule.  Have you tried using a [`rewrite`](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/rewrite) rule instead?

Comment: @mellamokb thanks for that you were correct.  If you post your answer i will mark it as correct.